# How to separate special string in android

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I need to Bold and italic where is start of the special character in the sentence(only @,#).

```
@ --> bold and italic
# --> bold
```

Example:

> Google Plus style #ListViews are all the rage these days on #Android because of the slick   @animations.

I want answer:

> Google Plus style #**ListViews** are all the rage these days on #**Android** because of the slick   @***animations***.

Comment: Any attempts from your side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String` object cannot store whether the text is `bold`, `italic`. It has only a character array.

`Bold` or `Italic` means a visual effect.

You can try something like following to detect what are the text you should add effects.

```
 String str = "Google Plus style #ListViews are all 
              the rage these days on #Android because of the slick @animations.";
 String[] arr = str.split(" ");
    for (String i : arr) {
        if (i.startsWith("#")) {
            // do something for #
        } else if(i.startsWith("@")){
            // do something for @
        } else {
           // other text 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably `startsWith` fits here better than `contains`.